# AWS IAM user with special permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam, aws-ec2

I am having following task to do.

I want to create 10 IAM users each user should have login username and password
and each IAM user should have separate ec2 instance that can not be visible to others.

for an example:
user1 user2 user2 .... user10

when user1 login in his dashboard he can see his own ec2 instance added by root/ super-admin user.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You use IAM policies for this ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_controlling.html ). It would probably be easiest to do this in conjunction with tags ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html )

Comment: You may also want to look into Service Catalog - https://aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/. This allows users to provision things themselves that you control.